# mocking method call in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, mocking

I have created *Product* model's method *in_stock()*. I need to mock it both in view and in template render.

My test:

```
def test_my_view(self):
    with patch.object(models.Product, 'in_stock', return_value='sldkfsdf'):
    # OR with patch.object(views.Product, 'in_stock', return_value='sldkfsdf'):

        response = self.client.get(reverse('my_view'))
    print response.content
```

My view:

```
def my_view(request):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
    print product.in_stock()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'product': product,
    })

    return render_to_response('product/my_view.xml', context)
```

My template:

```
{{ product.in_stock }}
```

**What I need** in stdout:

```
sldkfsdf
```

and in template:

```
sldkfsdf
```

**What I got** in stdout:

```
sldkfsdf
```

in template:

```
<value, returned by original Product.in_stock() method>
```

So call of Product.in_stock() in my_view works well. It doesn't work only in template. :( What I'm doing wrong? What I need to mock method in template render?

And I have very old Django - 1.1.1 :(

Python 2.7

Mock 1.0.1

Comment: Forgive me, but have you tried reloading the server?

Comment: @XORcist I running tests every time. Server is shutted down.

Comment: I'm confused: Isn't the test client accessing the url?

Comment: @XORcist you may want to read the FineManual about how the test client works.

Comment: @ambush why do you want to mock `Product.in_stock()` ? You can test the `response.content` against the `Product` instance's `.in_stock()` result.

Answer (score 1):

That has to do with the mock object being an instance of `MagicMock` instead of just `Mock`.

I guess this is due to Django accessing the methods/properties differently in the templates: `{{ obj.foo }}` could very well be both a method and an attribute on the object and that leads to magic methods like `__getitem__()` being used.

You can use `patch(new=Mock, …)` to have `Mock` instance created instead of `MagicMock`.

Comment: This answer would be so much better with an example.